# react-native fbsdk is returning email undefined

Tags: facebook, react-native, facebook-graph-api, fbsdk, react-native-fbsdk

I m trying to get information through the facebook sdk but so far I am getting only the id and the name of the user. I do have granted the premission but still the email is not popping out like name and id. 
I try to console.log(result.email) but i got undefined .

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { LoginButton, AccessToken ,GraphRequest, GraphRequestManager} from 'react-native-fbsdk';

export default class Login extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <LoginButton
    onLoginFinished={
      (error, result) => {
        if (error) {
          alert("login has error: " + result.error);
        } else if (result.isCancelled) {
          alert("login is cancelled.");
        } else {

          AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().then(
            (data) => {
              let accessToken = data.accessToken
              alert(accessToken.toString())

              const responseInfoCallback = (error, result) => {
                if (error) {
                  console.log(error)
                  alert('Error fetching data: ' + error.toString());
                } else {
                  console.log(result)
                  console.log(result.email)

                  alert('Success fetching data: ' + result.toString());
                }
              }

              const infoRequest = new GraphRequest(
                '/me',
                {
                  accessToken: accessToken,
                  parameters: {
                    fields: {
                      string: 'name,email'
            }
                  }
                },
                responseInfoCallback
              );

              // Start the graph request.
              new GraphRequestManager().addRequest(infoRequest).start()

            }
          )

        }
      }
    }
    onLogoutFinished={() => alert("logout.")}/>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: are you 100% sure you authorized with the email permission? did you debug the access token?

Comment: when i use a Test user i can get the email 

 how to get email access to any account

Comment: are you sure the account has an email? it´s not require, you know.